# DocFX output to Markdown

Tags: docfx

Looking at the flow DocFX seems to create .md files and then convert that to html when creating documentation.

Is there a way to make DocFX output to .md files instead of html ?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: I should misunderstand this question in my original answer. Actually, this is still an open feature request of DocFX, which is hard to achieve with the current architecture.

See: https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/issues/684

---

*Original answer*:

You should move the .md files from `content` to `resource` in `docfx.json`.

Take the follow `docfx.json` snippet as an example. All the `.md` files in `articles` will be converted to `.html` in the output.

```
...
"build": {
  "content": [
    {
      "files": ["articles/**.md"]
    }
  ]
}
...
```

If you hope `articles/sample.md` remains unconverted, you can change `docfx.json` as below:

```
...
"build": {
  "content": [
    {
      "files": ["articles/**.md"],
      "exclude": ["articles/sample.md"]
    }
  ]
  "resource": [
    {
      "files": ["articles/sample.md"]
    }
  ]
}
...
```

More information can be found on [DocFX User Manual](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx.exe_user_manual.html#3-2-properties-for-build).

Answer (score 2):

Experimental support for markdown generation has been added to docfx as of version [2.71.0](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/releases/tag/v2.71.0).